# Google Chrome Issue with Links ( href values shown after link in braces )

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink, href

had anyone ever this issue, that in chrome ( online, but not locally ) is showing the href attributes of an `<a>` Element after the Element Text?

```
<a href="about.html">About</a>
```

turns into About (about.html) in chrome.

Any other Browser is just doing fine.
If i only link to hash - links then there are no issues....

Any Ideas?

Comment: I use chrome all the time and I've never seen this except where it's been developed to work that way.  Is there a website you can show us that does this?

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same issue :
using boilerplate generated template from initializr

the styles in the bottom, in print media query section, was overriding other media queries : hiding background images and adding href attributes after links text value itself...

Hope it will help